# How to install figma or sketch in Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development

I'm following a tutorial in which they worked with sketch (only available on Mac), a program to package and mount applications, for example in React.

I searched for information and saw that figma can give me the services I sketch in Linux, but I can not find a way to install any of the two in my Ubuntu.

Can you give me any idea of how to install any of these programs that support the export of zeplin.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer

To install Figma:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo snap install --edge figma
```

If snap isn't installed, just do:

```
sudo apt install snap
```

If you get the error:

```
error: snap "figma" not found
```

Download the [Figma](https://github.com/302bis/figma-app-ubuntu/releases/download/0.5.0/figma_0.4_amd64.snap) snap package, and run

```
sudo snap install --dangerous figma_0.4_amd64.snap
```

You can use gdebi.  If you don't have it installed, you can install it by running:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

Download either the [64 Bit](https://github.com/ChugunovRoman/figma-linux/releases/download/v0.4.0/figma-linux_0.4.0_amd64.deb), or the [32Bit](https://github.com/ChugunovRoman/figma-linux/releases/download/v0.4.0/figma-linux_0.4.0_i386.deb) version depending on your system.

Once installed, open the downloaded file with gdebi, and click on `file --> Open` Choose the package you've downloaded, and open it.  Once opened, just click Install.

Edit:

The command for latest versions of Ubuntu should be updated. for 16.04 and later

```
sudo snap install figma-linux
```

Thanks to [Fireball.1](https://askubuntu.com/users/485874/fireball-1)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mitch , a question, do you have CLI version from which to work from desktop? Thank you

Comment: @gemita Take a look [Here](https://github.com/carloslfu/figma-app-linux).

Comment: Thanks for the support @Mitch , I have not managed to install in any way of the two that he offered me. Despite downloading the package, I got an error :`sudo snap install --dangerous figma_0.4_amd64.snap`  Error: _error: cannot open: "figma_0.4_amd64.snap"_

Comment: I have tried to follow the instructions of [the link](https://github.com/carloslfu/figma-app-linux) that I have provided, but I can not understand it, it is a bit complicated. Is there any other way to install that is not from the terminal? Thank you

Comment: how to revert back these commands . like uninstalling completely?

Comment: @xaif depending on the way you used to install you can use: `sudo snap remove <package>` or `sudo dpkg -P <package>` or `sudo apt-get purge <package>`

Comment: @Mitch the command for latest versions of ubuntu should be updated. for 16.04 and later `sudo snap install figma-linux`

Comment: @fireball.1 Thanks Info has been added to the answer with thanks to you.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo snap install figma-linux
```

installs the latest stable version (see https://snapcraft.io/figma-linux)

Comment: does the Flutter code-gen work on the Linux version?  https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/844008530039534144/FigmaToFlutter

Answer (score 0):

You can install more better figma destop app for linux form [here](https://github.com/ChugunovRoman/figma-linux).
You can download and install deb package from [release page](https://github.com/ChugunovRoman/figma-linux/releases). Or add repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chrdevs/figma
```